How can I save the URL(s), after making a copy (event) of a Google Sheets spreadsheet?
Overview: I have a Google Sheets template file which contains multiple tabs. When the file is opened, the user is prompted with a pop-up message to "Click link to create a Copy --> My Workbook copy". After the "My Workbook copy" is selected, the file is saved to a specific Google Drive folder, and a unique/new Google Spreadsheet file opens in which they can make edits.
Goal: I'm attempting to save the URL Links from the New Google Sheets file(s) each time a copy has been made (to the Reference tab). My goal is to have the URL link(s) added to the Reference sheet, in column C.
Current issue: The makeAcopy script (makes a copy of the spreadsheet and adds the file to the specified Google Drive), but the URL Link is not being added to the Reference sheet. I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach, unclear on whether the logic for adding the URL links to Reference sheet needs to be added in a separate event (On Open) or if it should be included in the makeAcopy script. Further guidance would be must appreciated it.
function onOpen(e){

const info = e.namedValues;
const blob = makeAcopy(info);
const date = Date;
const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,3).setValue(blob);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,2).setValue(fileName);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,1).setValue(date);

}



function makeAcopy(info){

    var nom = 'My Workbook copy'
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EylqqfqXWaSCJbvVmqrwJHcwGPUvlQYOZ0wSpvT_mMY')
        var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos"); //.next();
  
    const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MM.dd.yyyy");
  //var fileName = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).setName(`${nom}.${ds}`);
  var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).getId();


    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutput('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileID + '/" target="_blank">' + nom + '</a>')
        .setWidth(350) //optional
        .setHeight(50); //optional
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Click link to create a Copy');

    return fileID;
    //return fileName;

}

Dummy Spreadsheet

The reference sheet on your primary spreadsheet is a static location for the info to log to?

You may add the following to the makeAcopy script to achieve what you'd like to do:
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reference");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow() + 1;
  ss.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(ds);
  ss.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(nom);
  ss.getRange(lr, 3).setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileID + '/edit#gid=0');

The full code would become:
function onOpen(e) {

  const info = e.namedValues;
  makeAcopy(info);

}



function makeAcopy(info) {

  var nom = 'My Workbook copy'
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EylqqfqXWaSCJbvVmqrwJHcwGPUvlQYOZ0wSpvT_mMY')
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos");

  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM.dd.yyyy");
  var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).getId();


  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileID + '/" target="_blank">' + nom + '</a>')
    .setWidth(350)
    .setHeight(50);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Click link to create a Copy');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reference");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow() + 1;
  ss.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(ds);
  ss.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(nom);
  ss.getRange(lr, 3).setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileID + '/edit#gid=0');

  return fileID;

}


Note: I've removed const date = Date;, const entryRow = e.range.getRow();, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,3).setValue(blob);, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,2).setValue(fileName);, and SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName("Reference").getRange(entryRow,1).setValue(date); from onOpen(e) and did not change the other parts of the code to keep its integrity.

OUTPUT


Keep in mind that the makeCopy(name, destination) method copies the entire file, so if there are already links generated by others in the Reference sheet, they'll also be copied.


thanks for providing a concise, detailed response on why my version wasn't working appropriately. It is operating as expected

I'm unable to fully test your script because of the permissions for specific sheet IDs. However, I do believe that the problem results from trying to log the information using the onOpen's e.
Try adding a function like this into your script at the time you want.
function log(){

  refsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reference");
  refsheet.insertRows(2); // This logs top to bottom instead of appending to the bottom

  fileName = "file's name"; // Replace with the variable containing the name
  fileURL = "file's URL"; // Replace with the variable containing the URL
  urlToLog = [[Date(),fileName,fileURL]];

  refsheet.getRange(2,1,1,3).setValues(urlToLog);

}

You should then be able to add log() into the end of your script, or at some point after the variables it needs are set.

You can paste this example in your code and then run it from the GAS editor to see how, where, and what it logs, to determine if it is doing what you want.

thanks, your sample function is also very helpful
